# BigQuery IF condition then append value into Array - Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

In BQ (**Standard SQL**) I would like to Append a value into an existing Array IF a condition is satisfied

example

```
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)ecksofa'),ARRAY_CONCAT(prodcategory, ("1102")))
```

is this correct and efficient?

can I use multiple IFs and ARRAY_CONCAT in the same Query?

example

```
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)ecksofa'),ARRAY_CONCAT(prodcategory, ("1102"))) 
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)blablan'),ARRAY_CONCAT(prodcategory, ("1103")))
```

Comment: have you tried? does it give you expected result or error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess your purpose is like below for single IF (corrected your expression a little bit):

```sql
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)ecksofa'),
    ARRAY_CONCAT(prodcategory, ["1102"]), 
    prodcategory)
```

In order to chain multiple IF and concat the output array, I would use SQL like below:

```sql
ARRAY_CONCAT(prodcategory,
  IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)ecksofa'), ["1102"], []),
  IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)blablan'), ["1103"], []),
  ...
  )
```

To be more efficient, it is better to replace

```sql
REGEXP_CONTAINS(prodTitle, r'(?i)ecksofa')
=>
STRPOS(LOWER(prodTitle), 'ecksofa') != 0
```